# XML Validation error : EntityRef: expecting';' simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Estoy intentando obtener la información de una factura electrónica, pero me encuentro con este error cuando intento leer el archivo con `simplexml_load_file()` de PHP.

```
XML Validation error : EntityRef: expecting';' simplexml_load_file()
```

Debido a esto no puedo extraer la información que necesito, he indagado sobre el problema y encuentro que se debe al signo `&` que aparece en el nombre del proveedor como se muestra en la imagen.
Las soluciones que he encontrado hacen referencia a `simplexml_load_string()` por lo que en este caso no aplicaría ya que lo que se utiliza es un archivo externo.
Aprecio su tiempo y su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomendaría usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.load.php). Es una clase más completa, en principio no deberías tener problemas en este caso, y si lo tuvieras, la clase dispone de métodos adecuados para lidiar con la codificación, caracteres especiales, etc.

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo intentaré con ese para ver que pasa.